# Call a asynchronous method after another in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a `$watch` attached to the `appId` variable. SO, when appId get changed it called the `init` function

```
$scope.$watch('appId', function() {                
    if ($scope.appId != '') {
        console.log('Inside appId watch');
        $scope.init();
    }
});
```

`init()` calls two service methods

```
$scope.init = function() {

    if ($scope.appId === undefined || $scope.appId == '') return false;

    $scope.getPrincipals($scope.loadPrincipals);
    $scope.getSignaturesByAppId($scope.loadSignatures);     

};
```

The methods are

```
$scope.getSignaturesByAppId = function (callback) {
    ApplicationDataSource.getSignaturesByAppId($scope.appId, function (result) {
        callback(result);
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};


$scope.loadSignatures = function (result) {
    var signatureResultSet = angular.fromJson(result[0]);
    $scope.appSignatures = signatureResultSet;

    if($scope.appSignatures.length===0){
        $scope.setDefaultValue();
    }
    else{
        $scope.setValueFromObject();
    }

};

$scope.getPrincipals = function (callback) {
    ApplicationDataSource.getApplicationPrincipalList($scope.appId, function (result) {
        callback(result);
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};

$scope.loadPrincipals = function (result) {
    var guarantorResultSet = angular.fromJson(result[0]);
    $scope.principals = guarantorResultSet;
};
```

The problem occurs here. In `loadSignatures()`, I have called a method `setDefaultValue()` which needs the data retrieve from `loadPrincipals`. So, when, `loadSignatures` called, `principal` data is not updated.

How to call the  `$scope.getPrincipals($scope.loadPrincipals)` after `$scope.getSignaturesByAppId($scope.loadSignatures)` finish to retrieve data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Promises, here is an example:

```
var promise = callThatRunsInBackground();

promise.then(
  function(answer) {
    // do something
  },
  function(error) {
    // report something
  },
  function(progress) {
   // report progress
  });
```

So in your code it might look like (I will leave it to you to fix as I'm not going to compile or check for syntax errors):

```
var getPrincipals = $scope.getPrincipals($scope.loadPrincipals);

getPrincipals.then(
       function(datapayload) {  
            //do something with datapayload perhaps
            $scope.getSignaturesByAppId($scope.loadSignatures); 
     });
```

This will make it wait until getPrincipals is finished before running getSignaturesbyAppId

Comment: It says, can not read property `then` of undefined. Why the `getPrincipals` is undefined here ?

Comment: i cannot comment on why it's not working for you right now without downloading your project and debugging it myself. however, with promises you're on the correct path to solving the issue you're experiencing

Comment: Here is some additional reading: https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Answer (score 0):

What solve my issue is, I called `$scope.getSignaturesByAppId($scope.loadSignatures);` in `loadPrincipals` callback function, not in `init()`

```
$scope.loadPrincipals = function (result) {
       var guarantorResultSet = angular.fromJson(result[0]);
       $scope.principals = guarantorResultSet;

       $scope.getSignaturesByAppId($scope.loadSignatures); 
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, glad you got it sorted. This is basically a promise. Apologies for not giving more examples. Without an Angular version I'm usually just able to give advice to the point where you finally solve the issue you had

Comment: No problem. Got the idea from your answer. Accepted the answer.